# Connect to MongoDB by SSHTunnelForwarder

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo, ssh-tunnel

I am going to connect to mongodB in the server from clinet1. I created an SSHTunnelForwarder in the client to transfer my traffic in the port 27017 to the server and connect the server mongoDB database.

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (MONGO_HOST),
    ssh_username=MONGO_USER,
    ssh_password=MONGO_PASS,
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 27017),

)
server.start()

client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port)
```

but I received this error in server.start() :

```
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway python mongodb site:stackoverflow.com
```

Is there any solution to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare "MONGO_HOST" as a tuple? like below

```
MONGO_HOST = ('host', 22)
```

I looked for it `SSHTunnelForwarder`

I think this lib is connected by ssh method.

but I think you put not `ssh account` and `password` in `ssh_username` and `ssh_password`

Comment: Hi, I have added my host ip and 22 as port in MONGO-HOST and got this error : 2019-12-26 10:39:04,715| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway host_ip:22 : 111

Comment: MONGO_USER and MONGO_PASS are my server ssh username and password respectively.